# Using IF Statements in Excel with SUM formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have been having great difficulty in getting my formulae to work in Excel.

Basically I have an IF statement, like this:

```
In cell U5 :
=IF(K5="text","1","")
```

I had copied these all down to cell U500.

I then wanted to use SUM to combine all the numbers, so that I have a figure afterwards, like this:

```
In cell S5 :
=SUM(U5:U500)
```

I am getting a "0" in cell S5.

Why is this happening? I definitely have text in `K` column.

Comment: The cell needs to have a (number) 1. So there is a number that can be counted.

Comment: Why not just use COUNTIF() and skip the helper column, `=COUNTIF(K:K,"Text")`?

Comment: @ScottCraner Wow, didn't know that one. I will try that, as that will be better I think.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have done that. This is WAAAY better than using an IF statement then adding another column to sum them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're adding 1 to Excel as a string, not a number

You have

```
=IF(K5="text","1","")
```

You need

```
=IF(K5="text",1,"")
```

[image: enter code here]

Maybe having

```
=IF(K5="text",1)
```

is better, or

```
=IF(K5="text",1,0)
```

but depends on how you're using it else where.

Screen to prove it won't work if you add the number as a string (note in the image, the 5 in the formula is a string ("5")

[image]

Comment: Yes genius! Thanks. I have done this before, but I "thought" I knew it, so I just did it.